# Tooltipster ajax not able to show break line

Tags: jquery, ajax, tooltip

I am using the tooltipster plugin it works fine.

Below is my codes.

```
$(this).tooltipster({
                        content: 'Loading...',
                        functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {

                            // we'll make this function asynchronous and allow the tooltip to go ahead and show the loading notification while fetching our data
                            continueTooltip();

                            // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
                            if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    url: 'getDetails.php',
                                    success: function(data) {                                         
                                        // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                                        origin.tooltipster('content', data).data('ajax', 'cached');
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    });
```

For test below is my content in my getDetails.php

```
echo "Product Quantity : 200 <br/>";
echo "IP Quantity : 100 ";
```

The issue is I have added the break line but when it appear in the tooltip its not on the next line but all on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the option `contentAsHTML` to `true` when you call `tooltipster`, like this:

```
$('.tooltip').tooltipster({
    content: 'Loading...',
    contentAsHTML: true,
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {

        // we'll make this function asynchronous...
        continueTooltip();

        // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
        if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'getDetails.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    origin.tooltipster('content', data).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Just be sure you know that the value of `data` will always be well-formatted and safe (sanitized).

Comment: Ok thank you I will try your method. Another thing is this needed data('ajax', 'cached');?

Comment: I tried its worse now it just stop at the work loading and does not load my ajax content ?